# Deixar Selecionado item especifico ComboBox C# WinForms Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2017

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que contem um cadastro de clientes. Nesse cadastro existe um `ComboBox` que lista as cidades do banco de dados.

Minha dúvida é a seguinte: Como eu faço para deixar '*setado*' o nome de uma cidade especifica?

Por exemplo: primeira cidade que lista por padrão é '`ABADIA DE GOIAS`', porém eu gostaria que a cidade que aparecesse selecionada fosse '`SAO PAULO`', que esta lá pelo meio da minha lista. Como posso fazer isso?

> Código que lista cidades no ComboBox:

```
String nomeConexao = LoginInfo.StringConexao;
String string_conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[nomeConexao].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(string_conn);

String scom = "SELECT COD, CIDADE FROM CODMUNICIPIO ORDER BY CIDADE";

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(scom, conn);

DataTable dtResultado = new DataTable();
dtResultado.Clear();
CbCidade.DataSource = null;
da.Fill(dtResultado);

CbCidade.DataSource = dtResultado;
CbCidade.ValueMember = "COD";
CbCidade.DisplayMember = "CIDADE";
CbCidade.SelectedItem = "";
CbCidade.Refresh();
```

Comment: Isso é windowns forms ?

Comment: Isso mesmo Amadeu, Não tinha especificado, mas já corrigi.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode definir a propriedade `SelectedValue`:

```
CbCidade.SelectedValue = 1; //supondo que 1 seja código de Sao Paulo
```

ou pode definir o Texto também:

```
CbCidade.Text = "SAO PAULO";
```

Ainda que eu ache desnecessário executar uma nova query para buscar o código da cidade que deveria estar parametrizada, você deveria fazer assim:

```
String sql2 = "SELECT COD FROM  CODMUNICIPIO WHERE CIDADE = '" + CidadeEmpresa + "'"; 

SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(sql2, conn); 
SqlDataReader leitor = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
 if (leitor.HasRows)
 {
      leitor.Read();
      this.CbCidade.SelectedValue = leitor["COD"].ToString();
 }
```

**O Correto**, seria você armazenar o Código da cidade da empresa na variável `CidadeEmpresa` e não o nome dela, então faria apenas assim:

```
this.CbCidade.SelectedValue = CidadeEmpresa;
```

e se, ainda assim não for mudar o que é armazenado na variável, basta fazer assim:

```
this.CbCidade.Text = CidadeEmpresa;
```

Comment: Ola Rovann, problema é que tenho mais de 5000 cidades, e dependendo o caso vai mudar as cidades, A ideia é que se o cliente tem a empresa em PORTO ALEGRE, na hora de iniciar um cadastro de clientes ele já deixe setado PORTO ALEGRE pra facilitar na hora de cadastrar, se for SEDE NOVA deixa SEDE NOVA e assim por diante.

Comment: Pode fazer a seleção do item com `linq` em `dtResultado` e definir no `CbCidade.SelectedItem`. Tipo assim: `CbCidade.SelectedItem = dtResultado.SingleOrDefault(c => c.COD == codCidadeEmpresa);`. De modo que você esteja armazenando em `codCidadeEmpresa` a cidade que você quer sugerir de acordo com os seus critérios.

Comment: nesse caso seria um parâmetro do seu sistema, que deve ser configurado pelo seu cliente, Diego deu um exemplo de como selecionar esse parâmetro, mas definir o item selecionado no combo (e é o que está na pergunta) é como eu coloquei